# Powershell Copy in certain line

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I want to copy the content of my text file `test1.txt` in the line 52 of my second text file `test2.txt`.
To copy I use the following commands:

```
$a=Get-Content "C:\Users\Administrator\Destop\test1.txt"
"$a"|Out-File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test2.txt" -Append
```

But how can I define a specific line? 
And how to overwrite when there is something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Get-Content](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113310) cmdlet basically returns a object array thus you can use some [array range operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847882.aspx):

```
$a = Get-Content "C:\Users\Administrator\Destop\test1.txt"
$b = Get-Content "C:\Users\Administrator\Destop\test2.txt"

@($b[0 .. 51], $a) | out-File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test2.txt"
```

Comment: Works great. Thank you !