# Using Powershell to copy multiple lines by line number

Tags: powershell

I have a text file with about 300,000 rows. I need to copy about 188 lines and I have a list of line numbers to extract.

Is there a function that will allow me to do this faster than using crtl+G and keying in each line number manually?

Thanks

Comment: I searched for **powershell copy specific line from file**. I think the answers to these two SO questions may help. [Powershell Copy in certain line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36786533/powershell-copy-in-certain-line) and [Copy specific lines from a text file to separate file using powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41010494/copy-specific-lines-from-a-text-file-to-separate-file-using-powershell) There were lots of other search results that I did not look at. One of them may help - if the above two do not.

Comment: `Get-Content .\in.txt |Select-Object -Index 0, 3, 8, ... |Set-Content .\out.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the very fast `switch` for this as it processes a text file line-by-line.

This example starts the line indexing at `1`.

```
# the list of line numbers to fetch
$linesToFetch = 1,4,7,9,12
$currentLine  = 1
$result  = switch -File 'D:\Test\test.txt' {
    default { if ($linesToFetch -contains $currentLine++) { $_ }}
}

# write to file and also display on screen by using -PassThru
$result | Set-Content -Path 'D:\Test\excerpt.txt' -PassThru
```

Comment: Okay, that's hilarious in the best way -- in that it's very clever! [`switch` is a switch statement](https://ss64.com/ps/switch.html) and the `-File` option (which I'd never seen used with `switch` before) is just to say, "Instead of me feeding you values, take them from a file, line by line". #TIAL: You can also feed `switch` a pipeline. Very clever!

Answer (score 0):

you can use [get-content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-7.2):

to get the first 188 lines:

```
get-content -Path .\yourfile.txt -TotalCount 188 | set-content -Path .\out_path.txt
```

you can print specific using `skip`:

```
Get-Content -Path ".\yourfile.txt" -First 188 | select -Skip 10
```

to get specific lines:

```
get-content -Path .\yourfile.txt | Select-Object -Index 0, 1, 2,... | set-content -Path .\out_path.txt
```

Comment: Will that allow them to select which 188 lines to extract or will it take the 188 first lines?